# TensorFlow Custom loss function error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'"

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm creating a multi-layer perceptron (MLP), a type of Artificial Neural Network (ANN). I've successfully configured MLPs before but this time I need a custom loss function involving the derivatives of the ANN with respect to some of the input variables.

The loss function I’m trying to implement is the following:
[image]

Where:

- w is the weight matrix
- i represents the index for the neuron
- j represents the index for the layer
- C is the function we are trying to approximate
- C_ANN is the ANN
- ξ  are the inputs to a neuron
- λ and m are constants
- K and T are two of the ANN’s inputs (strike and Time to Maturity)

So basically this loss function is a MSE (the picture lacks the division by the number of neurons so that we have a mean, but the error comes from a paper I'm referencing) + 3 constraints.

The code (simplified by having only 1 constraint):

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np6


# Hyperparameters
n_hidden_layers = 2 # Number of hidden layers.
n_units = 128 # Number of neurons of the hidden layers.
n_batch = 64 # Number of observations used per gradient update.
n_epochs = 30


# Sample data
x_train = {'strike':  [200, 2925], 'Time to Maturity': [0.312329, 0.0356164], 
        "RF Rate": [0.08, 2.97], 
        "Sigma 20 Days Annualized": [0.123251, 0.0837898], 
        "Underlying Price": [1494.82, 2840.69]
        }

call_X_train = pd.DataFrame (x_train, columns = ['strike', "Time to Maturity", 
                                                  "RF Rate", 
                                                  "Sigma 20 Days Annualized", 
                                                  "Underlying Price"]
                             )

x_test = {'strike':  [200], 'Time to Maturity': [0.0356164], 
        "RF Rate": [2.97], 
        "Sigma 20 Days Annualized": [0.0837898], 
        "Underlying Price": [2840.69]
        }

call_X_test = pd.DataFrame (x_test, columns = ['strike', "Time to Maturity", 
                                                  "RF Rate", 
                                                  "Sigma 20 Days Annualized", 
                                                  "Underlying Price"]
                            )

y_train = np.array([1285.25, 0.8])
call_y_train = pd.Series(y_train)

y_test = np.array([0.8])
call_y_test = pd.Series(y_test)


# Creates hidden layers
def hl(tensor, n_units):
    hl_output = layers.Dense(n_units, activation = layers.LeakyReLU())(tensor)
    return hl_output

# Create model using Keras' Functional API
def mlp3_call(n_hidden_layers, n_units):
    # Create input layer
    inputs = keras.Input(shape = (call_X_train.shape[1],))
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 1)(inputs)

    # Create hidden layers
    for _ in range(n_hidden_layers):
        x = hl(x, n_units)

    # Create output layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation = keras.activations.softplus)(x)

    # Actually create the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    
    return model


# Penalization function used in the Custom loss function
def pen(x, lamb, m):
    return tf.where(x < 0, 0.0, lamb * x**m)

# Custom loss function
def constrained_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    
    # Parameters of penalization function
    lamb = 10
    m = 4
    
    # Function formula
    loss = (keras.backend.mean(keras.backend.square(y_pred - y_true)) # MSE
    
            + pen(-tf.gradients(y_pred, model.input[:,1]), lamb, m) # constraint
            
            )
    
    return loss
    
model = mlp3_call(n_hidden_layers, n_units) 
model.compile(loss = constrained_mse, optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),)
history = model.fit(call_X_train, call_y_train, batch_size = n_batch, 
                    epochs = n_epochs, validation_split = 0.01, verbose = 1)
```

I get the error message in the title: `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'"`. I know the problem is in the constraint because I’ve tried running the code without it and it runs fine. I thought it had to do with the pen function and I tried `tf.convert_to_tensor` but nothing changed.

I’m also not sure if the constraint is doing what I want it to do, never had to use derivatives before.

EDIT1 - Traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\Desktop\Code\MLP3\mlp3_call_SO.py", line 108, in <module>
    model.compile(loss = constrained_mse, optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 446, in compile
    self._compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics()

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1592, in _compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1652, in _prepare_total_loss
    per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(y_true, y_pred)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\losses.py", line 221, in call
    return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\Desktop\Code\MLP3\mlp3_call_SO.py", line 92, in constrained_mse
    model.input[:,0]),

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 274, in gradients_v2
    unconnected_gradients)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gradients_util.py", line 536, in _GradientsHelper
    gradient_uid)

  File "C:\Users\Diogo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gradients_util.py", line 167, in _DefaultGradYs
    with _maybe_colocate_with(y.op, gradient_uid, colocate_gradients_with_ops):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'
```

EDIT2: Replaced the constraint in the custom loss function with a simpler one.

EDIT3: If I check the value of tf.gradients(y_pred, model.input[:,1])[0] in a debug, it is None. The problem may be there (I'm investigating why the gradient would return None). Notice I added "[0]" after ")".

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback of the error ?